# How do I notify RecyclerView items that they become visible on screen or disappeared

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView` with items that plays animations and I would like to start and stop playing those animations when item appears on and disappears from the screen.

I found [`addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener)) method of `RecyclerView` in official doc. But when I tried to use it Android Studio cant find such method.

Is there any other listener I can use ? Or should I set some kind of ScrollListener and check it there?